# Populating a variable with xsl choose

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="a" select="'a'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="b" select="'b'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="c" select="'c'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$a !=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$b !=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$c"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
```

The result variable is populated, here i used the xsl choose statements. I just wanted to know if there is any other efficient or simple way to populate the result variable, based on the same logic as xsl choose.

Something like this

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="$a | $b | $c" />
```

The above will work for nodesets, not for variables. Any inputs?xsl 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like this
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="result" select="$a | $b | $c" />
> ```
>
> The above will work for nodesets, not for variables. Any inputs?xsl
>   1.0

**This is wrong!** The above `result` variable is defined to contain the union of three node-sets -- not just one of them, depending on whether some other(s) of them are empty.

**A correct XPath expression in this case is**:

```
$a | $b[not($a)] | $c[not($a | $b)]
```

---

When These three variables aren't node-sets but strings and if these string values can have *any length* (not only length of 1), the corresponding XPath expression is similar:

```
concat($a, 
       substring($b, 1 div ($a = '')), 
       substring($c, 1 div (concat($a, $b) = ''))
       )
```

Here we use the fact that:

`substring($s, $k)` is the empty string `''`

whenever

```
$k >= string-length($s)
```

and

```
substring($s, 1) = $s
```

Also:

```
1 div false()
```

is `positive Infinity`

(`false()` is converted to 0 when used in arithmetic operations).

and by definition

```
positive Infinity > $k
```

for every integer `$k`.

Therefore,

```
substring($s, 1 div $somethingFalse) = ''
```

and

```
substring($s, 1 div $somethingTrue) = $s
```

---

**Finally,** if it is guaranteed that the three variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c` can have as value only a single character, than we can use just:

```
substring(concat($a, $b, $c), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Super for xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the variables are bound to nodesets then `$a | $b | $c` yields the union of those nodesets and not an alternative so I am not sure what you want to explain by presenting that example.

In your first code sample you have three variables with values of type string where each holds a single character so you might be able to do `<xsl:variable name="result" select="substring(concat($a, $b, $c), 1, 1)"/>` if a single character or an empty string is all you expect and you want to find the very first character in the "set" of variables. But in general XSLT 1.0 might require verbose `xsl:choose/when/otherwise` coding.